# shortcut keys for adding existing items link in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

There is a feature in visual studio to have a link to an existing item in another project as stated in "[How do I create Visual Studio shortcut files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458301/how-do-i-create-visual-studio-shortcut-files)". Is there any Key Combination for that feature?

for example (Ctrl+Shift+C) and Drag the existing item to another project and that action creates a link to that existing item. How and where may I define that shourcut keys?

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2010, exists a Command called "File.AddExistingProject". In Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard you can assign a shortcut to this command, for example I've assigned Alt+Shift+P.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have a shortcut key directly, but you can get the effect in a macro by using the ProjectItems.AddFromFile method.  This creates a link from the source file in your project.

To assign a shortcut key to your macro, go to Tools/Options/Keyboard within Visual Studio.  You can assign shortcut keys there.