# Common config file in a multiple-project solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I'm working on a medium n-tier solution consisting of 2 web projects and a Winforms project as presentations, plus a Model and Service tier.

All these projects share the same settings (which are now hard-coded for simplicity). I'm looking to put these settings in a config file (not in the database) that can be reused among all the projects and tiers, but I'm not quite sure how. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458301/how-do-i-create-visual-studio-shortcut-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the config file in one of the projects physically, and in the rest, [add the config file as a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9f4t9t92%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).